# unauthorized error when using HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, basic-authentication

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleProgram
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private const string URL = "https://sun.domain.com/v1/service/token";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@client", "admin");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "admin", "admin"))));
            //  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;  // Blocking call!
            String res = response.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting unauthorized error even though I am passing the correct credentials. Any ideas?

I tried almost all the answers posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code - it's very hard to read with no indentation...

Comment: You've also given no background information, so it's very difficult to tell what you're trying to do, edit the question and give some more information about what your actually trying to accomplish in general.

Comment: Depends on what type of authentication `"https://sun.domain.com/v1/service/token"` supports.

Comment: Sorry for not properly indenting the code.

Comment: I am trying to consume a c# rest service using httpclient. I will look into the type of authentication the server is using now. Thanks.

Comment: So i checked on the authentication part.It uses Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 7):

For Basic Authentication, you need to send the credentials in an authorization header called "Basic" with base64-encoded "username:password" as the value. This should get the job done:

```
var headerVal = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin@client:admin"));
var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerVal);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;
```

Comment: Todd, I tried your method but it is the same unauthorized response again. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I didn't even notice the commented-out line. Hmm. You tried without the HttpClientHandler, i.e. just `new HttpClient();` ? Don't include that AND the auth header. And did you try authenticating at that URL from a browser? I really suspect your code is not the problem.

Comment: Todd, there was a problem with the url itself. Thanks. I figured it out.