# 401 unauthorized with C# HttpClient Library

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to upgrade code to HttpClient from HttpWebRequest in c#.

I am unable to authenticate third party service with HttpClient and i didn't see this problem with postman or httpwebrequest library

I have tried with postman.

Postman Console window reference:

GET /api/v2/geocodes/a973-5a1c5d435990
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: JWT ey-----iJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTYzMDEwOTg4LCJqdGkiOiIwNWM3
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8d46fa25-698c-477d-a86e-bbc546ad0470
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.0
Accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://api.concept.quincus.com/api/v2/geocodes/3d0a4758-611e-448f-a973-5a1c5d435990

working code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                        quincusGeoCodeDataRequest.endpoint);

                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "JWT " + quincusGeoCodeDataRequest.quincusTokenData.token);
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                    string response;

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        streamReader.Close();
                    }
```

I am trying to implement same code with HttpClient Library

```
var response = string.Empty;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri("http://sample.com/3d0a4758"),

                };

                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT","eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC");

                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            }
            return response;
```

It is always returning 401 unauthorized. I don't know where is an issue ?

I want to see how to implement httpclient for above httpwebrequest code snippet

Comment: try changing `request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT","eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC");` to  `request.Headers.Add("JWT","eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC");`

Comment: No Luck. Still i am seeing same error.

Status Code: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: I don't know, but i think you need to send credentials in authorization header.There is a answer here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515437/unauthorized-error-when-using-httpclient) and i don't know this fix your problem

Comment: Hi @pnet, 

I didn't use Basic Authentication to pass credentials in headers. I am using JWT token here. That same token being authenticated from httpwebrequest.